# How to add a modifier to a quoted regular (qr) expression

Tags: regex, perl, modifier, stringification, qr-operator

Is there an easy way to add regex modifiers such as 'i' to a quoted regular expression? For example:

```
$pat = qr/F(o+)B(a+)r/;
$newpat = $pat . 'i'; # This doesn't work
```

The only way I can think of is to `print "$pat\n"` and get back `(?-xism:F(o+)B(a+)r)` and try to remove the 'i' in `?-xism:` with a substitution

Answer (score 6):

You cannot put the flag inside the result of `qr` that you already have, because it’s protected.  Instead, use this:

```
$pat = qr/F(o+)B(a+)r/i;
```

Answer (score 2):

You can modify an existing regex as if it was a string as long as you recompile it afterwards

```
  my $pat = qr/F(o+)B(a+)r/;
  print $pat, "\n";
  print 'FOOBAR' =~ $pat ? "match\n" : "mismatch\n";

  $pat =~ s/i//;
  $pat = qr/(?i)$pat/;
  print $pat, "\n";
  print 'FOOBAR' =~ $pat ? "match\n" : "mismatch\n";
```

**OUTPUT**

```
  (?-xism:F(o+)B(a+)r)
  mismatch
  (?-xism:(?i)(?-xsm:F(o+)B(a+)r))
  match
```

Comment: +1 for showing the appropriate way to plant a modifier into an existing regex. The `(?…)` part is documented in http://perldoc.perl.org/perlre.html#Extended-Patterns

Comment: This doesn't work after Perl 5.12 because the regex stringification changed.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like the only way is to stringify the RE, replace (-i) with (i-) and re-quote it back:

```
my $pat = qr/F(o+)B(a+)r/;
my $str = "$pat";
$str =~ s/(?<!\\)(\(\?\w*)-([^i:]*)i([^i:]*):/$1i-$2$3:/g;
$pati = qr/$str/;
```

UPDATE: perl 5.14 quotes regexps in a [different way](http://www.effectiveperlprogramming.com/blog/735), so my sample should probably look like

```
my $pat = qr/F(o+)B(a+)r/;
my $str = "$pat";
$str =~ s/(?<!\\)\(\?\^/(?^i/g;
$pati = qr/$str/;
```

But I don't have perl 5.14 at hand and can't test it.

UPD2: I also failed to check for escaped opening parenthesis.

Comment: This won't work anymore because the regex stringification doesn't do -options in Perl 5.14.

Comment: @briandfoy: Thanks for poining out. I've updated my answer, but I'm not sure that the 5.14 part works.