# perl: how to get the original regex from the precompiled version?

Tags: perl

Simple code:

```
use 5.014;
use warnings;

my $re = <DATA>;
chomp $re;
my $re2 = qr/$re/;
say $re2;
__END__
^\w$
```

result:

```
(?^u:^\w$)      #added the (?^u:
```

Is any correct way to decompile $re2 getting back the original regex?

Motivation: the regex is an config value, so need:

- read it
- compile it
- save it to the file for the later use.

But can't save the compiled regex for the later use, because in every compiling the regex got expanded with the (?^u:, so after several cycles i ended with like:

```
(?^u:(?^u:(?^u:(?^u:(?^u:^\w$)))))
```

therefore the question are:

- is here any correct way, how to save the compiled version?
- if no way - how to decompile, to getting the original version?
- any idea?

Comment: You say you read the pattern from a file, so you have what you want to save to a file, so why don't you save it?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

While I would just keep the string copy around for data usage, and then compile a copy when I needed to use it, you can also use the [regexp_pattern](http://perldoc.perl.org/re.html#Exportable-Functions) function from the core `re` module to return the pattern used to create a compiled regex:

```
use re 'regexp_pattern';

print regexp_pattern qr/^\w$/;
```

prints

```
^\w$
```

Comment: That's is exactly what i need. Working with perl above 5.10 - so fine... ;) THANX!

Comment: That's not what it prints, at least not in 5.14.

Comment: @ikegami => I have 5.10.1 here at work, and that is exactly what it prints.  Also, it does not fail for `qr/foo\/bar/` it simply returns a value that does not cater to those quoting characters...

Comment: From the documentation on [regexp_pattern](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?re): `In list context it returns a two element list, the first element containing the pattern and the second containing the modifiers used when the pattern was compiled.` When testing, I found that the two examples mentioned above print a list, where the second element is `u`.

Answer (score 4):

[`re::regexp_pattern`](http://search.cpan.org/dist/perl/ext/re/re.pm#Exportable_Functions)

Credits to [vpit](http://search.cpan.org/~vpit) for pointing this out on [MagNET #perl](http://irc.perl.org).

Comment: Just read than here is another answer for the 'use re ...'. Thanx daxim too - unfortunately can accept only one..

Answer (score 3):

The original is an *operator*, not a regex pattern. Only looking at the first value returned by `regexp_pattern` (the pattern) results in information loss. You also need to look at the second (the flags).

```
qr/foo/                  # pat: foo  flags: u
qr/foo/u                 # pat: foo  flags: u
use re '/u';  qr/foo/    # pat: foo  flags: u

qr/foo/a                 # pat: foo  flags: a
use re '/a';  qr/foo/    # pat: foo  flags: a

qr/foo/i                 # pat: foo  flags: ui
use re '/i';  qr/foo/    # pat: foo  flags: ui
use re '/a';  qr/foo/i   # pat: foo  flags: ai
use re '/ai'; qr/foo/    # pat: foo  flags: ai
```

To get the closest possible you can get to the original operator, you want

```
use re qw( regexp_pattern );
my ($pat, $flags) = regexp_pattern($re);
$pat =~ s{/}{\\/}g;
say qq{qr/$pat/$flags};
```

Comment: I'm compiling my regexs without flags, so Erics simple version is enough for me. Anyway, Thanks much for the detailed explanation!!!

Comment: @jm666, Again, if you know that, why do you need to extract the original pattern from a re?

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps as simple as:

```
...
($reoriginal = $re2) =~ s{^\(\?.+:(.+)\)}{$1};
say $reoriginal
```

Comment: Beware, version inconsistent: http://stackoverflow.com/q/8082617#comment-10190574